# ExtJS6 Store Not Found on Tree Grid

Tags: treegrid, extjs6

Greetings fellow ExtJS developers.  I am attempting to build a tree grid; however the store property on the grid doesn't seem to work when the store is defined as a class extension.  Too much code to put here but I do have it fiddled:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/13v0

Am I required to define the store in the tree grid configuration?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, are you having an issue with `Ext.grid.Panel` or `Ext.tree.Panel` ? If you're talking about `Ext.grid.Panel` then I was having the same issue and I figured out how to fix it (I'll answer your question if it's the case)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved as I did not include the store in the "stores" configuration of the application.